# Yarn Install Error: Package subpath error

Tags: npm, scripting, yarnpkg

I am currently working on a project following the documentation in this github repo.

[github repo](https://github.com/ava-labs/avalanche-wallet-sdk)

I first clone the repo into a folder. I then cd into the folder and do a run yarn install to get all dependencies. I get the following error. I have node v17.2.0 installed.

```
(base) Eddys-MacBook-Pro:avalanche-wallet-sdk eddyarce$ yarn install
yarn install v1.22.17
warning ../../../../../package.json: No license field
[1/5]   Validating package.json...
[2/5]   Resolving packages...
success Already up-to-date.
$ husky install && yarn build:prod
husky - Git hooks installed
yarn run v1.22.17
warning ../../../../../package.json: No license field
$ rollup -c --environment BUILD:production
Error loading `tslib` helper library.
[!] Error: Package subpath './package.json' is not defined by "exports" in /Users/eddyalvarado_1/Documents/GitHub/plasma-wallet-web3/js/avalanche-wallet-sdk/node_modules/rollup-plugin-typescript2/node_modules/tslib/package.json
Error: Package subpath './package.json' is not defined by "exports" in /Users/eddyalvarado_1/Documents/GitHub/plasma-wallet-web3/js/avalanche-wallet-sdk/node_modules/rollup-plugin-typescript2/node_modules/tslib/package.json
    at new NodeError (node:internal/errors:371:5)
    at throwExportsNotFound (node:internal/modules/esm/resolve:429:9)
    at packageExportsResolve (node:internal/modules/esm/resolve:683:3)
    at resolveExports (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:482:36)
    at Function.Module._findPath (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:522:31)
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:919:27)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:778:27)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:999:19)
    at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:102:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/eddyalvarado_1/Documents/GitHub/plasma-wallet-web3/js/avalanche-wallet-sdk/node_modules/rollup-plugin-typescript2/src/tslib.ts:11:23)

error Command failed with exit code 1.
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this command.
error Command failed with exit code 1.
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/install for documentation about this command.
```

Answer (score 1):

https://github.com/ezolenko/rollup-plugin-typescript2/issues/286
Upgrade your tslib version (>=0.31.0) or downgrade your node version (<17.0.0)